# Unable to filter data from other spreadhseet paste in master sheet based on dates in google spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

First of all thank you for the efforts made in this site. As an individual and a beginner i have learnt from my errors made. Thanks for all who have contributed & extended their support.
Thanks for this.

Here is a small program written which is not working (no output)seen , i have tried it in many ways but in vain. please help me to find a solution for this.
the aim of this program was to filter the data from 4 sheets and paste into current sheet (master). this filter is based on date values.

Conditions of dates are taken from the master sheet in columns in (b2 & d2)dates. this are to be filtered out based in column no.18 which has dates in client sheets.

```
function myFunction3() {

var source = ['0AjkkHlm3kCphdGhSWnlxWmFsakZ2aFhMSHl6SlF3M1E',
                '0AjkkHlm3kCphdHY2aXpjTVJEMlFRYVBST0ZPYzNwRFE',
                '0AjkkHlm3kCphdEc5ZHFpeHVlc241SlFKWGJDeXFKLXc',
                '0AjkkHlm3kCphdG9WVjVRRnQ3RlFlcllhd1JGallXVmc'];

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
// get start date from sheet
var sDate = ss.getSheetByName('123').getRange("B2").getValue();
// get end date from sheet
var eDate = ss.getSheetByName('123').getRange("D2").getValue();
// days between
var Dura = ss.getSheetByName('123').getRange("E1").getValue(); 

  var codes = new Array();

  for (var k = 0; k < Dura; k++){ 
      var d = new Date(sDate);
      d.setDate(d.getDate()+ k);
      codes[k] = d;
  }

  var numCodes = codes.length;
  var copied = [];
  for (var k = 0; k < numCodes; k++) {
    copied[k] = [];
  }

//get data from external sheets for comparision
  for (var i = 0; i < source.length; i++) {
    var tempCopy = SpreadsheetApp.openById(source[i]).getSheetByName('Footfall-Format').getDataRange().getValues();
    // comparision starts
    for (var j = 0; j < tempCopy.length; j++) {
      var codeIndex = codes.indexOf(tempCopy[j][5]);
      if (codeIndex > -1) copied[codeIndex].push(tempCopy[j]);
    }
  }
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets();
  for (var m = 0; m < numCodes; m++) {
    if (copied[m][0] != undefined) {
      var gensheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('123');
      gensheet.getRange(5, 1, 1500, 18).clear({contentsOnly:true});
      gensheet.getRange(5, 1, copied[m].length, copied[m][0].length).setValues(copied[m]);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fundamental problem is that you are comparing objects for equality - in this case, you're comparing `Date` objects. Even when the date represented by two of these objects is the same, the object comparison comes up false unless you're actually referencing the same *object*. You can read more about this in [Compare two dates with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-dates-with-javascript).

Here's a simple change to your script, using `toDateString()`, that will ensure your `codes[]` array contains string values that can be compared with values in `tempCopy[j][5]`.

```
function myFunction3() {

var source = ['0AjkkHlm3kCphdGhSWnlxWmFsakZ2aFhMSHl6SlF3M1E',
                '0AjkkHlm3kCphdHY2aXpjTVJEMlFRYVBST0ZPYzNwRFE',
                '0AjkkHlm3kCphdEc5ZHFpeHVlc241SlFKWGJDeXFKLXc',
                '0AjkkHlm3kCphdG9WVjVRRnQ3RlFlcllhd1JGallXVmc'];

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
// get start date from sheet
var sDate = ss.getSheetByName('123').getRange("B2").getValue();
// get end date from sheet
var eDate = ss.getSheetByName('123').getRange("D2").getValue();
// days between
var Dura = ss.getSheetByName('123').getRange("E1").getValue(); 

  var codes = new Array();

  for (var k = 0; k < Dura; k++){ 
      var d = new Date(sDate);
      d.setDate(d.getDate()+ k);
      codes[k] = d.toDateString(); //***** Make array of Strings, not Dates
  }

  var numCodes = codes.length;
  var copied = [];
  for (var k = 0; k < numCodes; k++) {
    copied[k] = [];
  }

//get data from external sheets for comparision
  for (var i = 0; i < source.length; i++) {
    var tempCopy = SpreadsheetApp.openById(source[i]).getSheetByName('Footfall-Format').getDataRange().getValues();
    // comparision starts
    for (var j = 4; j < tempCopy.length; j++) {  // start at 4 to skip headers
      if (typeof tempCopy[j][5] != "object") break;   // skips strings, but could improve
      // Search for String match of date from input record
      var codeIndex = codes.indexOf(tempCopy[j][5].toDateString());
      if (codeIndex > -1) copied[codeIndex].push(tempCopy[j]);
    }
  }
  // This part has bugs... each day overwrites the previous
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets();
  for (var m = 0; m < numCodes; m++) {
    if (copied[m][0] != undefined) {
      var gensheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('123');
      gensheet.getRange(5, 1, 1500, 18).clear({contentsOnly:true});
      gensheet.getRange(5, 1, copied[m].length, copied[m][0].length).setValues(copied[m]);
    }
  }
}
```

As @Serge points out, there are other problems in this code.

- `d.getDate()+ k` does not handle month-end, so you need to do that yourself.
- The last part of your script that handles the output via `setValues()` needs to be debugged. As it is, each day overwrites the previous day's values from the `copied[]` array. I'm not sure what requirement you were trying to meet with this, so I left it alone, but it needs attention.